# how to use return type a class in php 7

Tags: php

- I tried my code as below. but in this, I return a blank object when an error occurred.
- Is it ok to write return blank object? when the return type is class.

  ```
  public static function createBook($book_data): BookModel
  {
      try {
          $book = new BookModel;
          $book->fill($book_data);
          $book->save();
          return $book;
      }
      catch(\Exception $e) {
         log::error($e->getMessage());
         $book = new BookModel;
         return $book;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Sure this is fine. Your `BookModel` is a valid object of that class, be it filled or not. Now it might be that your own code later stumbles over that object if you assume it being "filled". But that is not an issue of the panguage, but of your implementation not being robust enough then.

Comment: IMHO- returning an instance of the object in this case is not correct.  How does the calling routine know if the book is created or not?  It would be so easy for some other programmer to come along and assume that as he has an instance of a book that everything has worked OK.  Is the Exception important - should it be passed on up the chain - depends on how your app is built.

Answer (score 1):

You're in for pain if you return empty objects:

- If you use database's auto increment ids, then it wont exist on this empty model.
- Any other required fields will not be filled in. (E.g., book with no author and no content?)

Although in some situations empty state objects are okay, if you have to ask then you most likely will handle it incorrectly anyway.

Since you have to check against this empty object anyway, returning null is still an okay solution. If you're on php7.1 then the return type can stay (note the questionmark).

```
public static function createBook($book_data): ?BookModel
{
    try {
        $book = new BookModel;
        $book->fill($book_data);
        $book->save();

        return $book;
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
       log::error($e->getMessage());

       return null;
    }
}
```

IMO, a better aproach would be to allow the error to propagate up and let you catch it somewhere else. Looks like you're using laravel, so the error will be logged anyway. So, for example, if you're in a database transaction, the transaction can fail safely:

```
public static function createBook($book_data): BookModel
{
    $book = new BookModel;
    $book->fill($book_data);
    $book->save();

    return $book;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I say it depends on what you want to do if (in this case) the exception is thrown.

- If you want to let the app know that something went wrong, you should return `false`. Returning an empty `BookModel` is basically saying that everything went fine and it's much easier to check if something is `false` than checking if an attribute of an object is empty.
- If it doesn't really mind that the book is empty (i.e. your code doesn't assume books are always filled), I think it is okay to return an empty book. However i'd change the code a bit:

  ```
  public static function createBook($book_data): BookModel
  {
      $book = new BookModel();
      try {
          $book->fill($book_data);
          $book->save();
      }
      catch(\Exception $e) {
          log::error($e->getMessage());
      }
      return $book;
  }
  ```